# Why Does Python List Multiplication Create A Single List with Multiple Elements?

Tags: python, list

In python, `['a'] * 4` gives `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`. Why not `[['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a']]`?

Comment: If you do [['a']] you get the result you wish to get. You are multiplying the elements inside the list, not the lists themselves.

Comment: These sorts of questions really boil down to "because that's what the people who designed the language decided that should mean"

Comment: @MWaz I'd be careful of that.  List multiplication will give you duplicate objects, which can lead to surprising results when the objects are mutable.

Comment: Would you accept "it is easier to use and there are far more use cases for a single flat list than a nested list" as an answer?

Comment: I'm satisfied with @MWaz and juanpa's combined comments. I think they should form an answer: "It's the way Python works", and "you are multiplying the elements inside the list, not the lists."

Comment: @Robin - I believe the answer is Guido [took inspiration from existing functional languages](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/04/origins-of-pythons-functional-features.html) but I don't know if this applies for list operations..

Answer (score 5):

Because, just as with multiplication of integers is repeated addition, multiplication with a lis is repeated concatenation.

```
>>> ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> ['a'] * 4
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> 4 * ['a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

This obeys various other laws as well:

- Distribution: `lst * n + lst * m == lst * (n + m)`
- Zero property: `lst * 0 == 0 * lst == []`
- Multiplicative identity: `lst * 1 == lst`.

The above are also consistent with the empty list `[]` being the additive identity,

```
['a'] + [] == [] + ['a'] == ['a']
```

since

```
['a'] + [] == ['a'] * 1 + ['a'] * 0  # zero property and multiplicative identity
           == ['a'] * (1 + 0)        # distribution
           == ['a'] * 1              # integer addition
           == ['a']                  # multiplicative identity
```

---

Arguably, `list * int` shouldn't be defined at *all*. The main use case, to quickly produce a list of `n` identical elements, is more safely done using list comprehensions (which were added to the language later). `[x] * n` creates a list of references to the single element `x`, which is usually *not* what you want if `x` is mutable. `[x for _ in range(n)]`, on the other hand, creates a list of independent objects defined by `x`, which *is* what you want when `x` is mutable.

Comment: It seems to me there must be an implicit assumption here which makes something obvious to you which is not to me. To me it's obvious that adding multiple items of type "list" should result in multiple items of type "list". I think the answers and comments so far are equivalent to "because that's how Python does it." I'm thinking maybe there's some hidden set theory or something going on in the background.

Comment: A list is effectively a free monoid, and a monoid is built from a set of elements, an associative binary operation, and an identity element for that operation. In the case of lists, the operation is concatenation with the empty list as the identity. Multiplication is just repetition of that operation; multiplication of two *lists* themselves is undefined: `['a'] * ['a']`, for example, is a type error.

Comment: One *could* define `['a'] * 2` to be `[['a'], ['a']]`, but that would be inconsistent with how `['a'] + ['a']` is defined with no apparent benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Much like multiplication with numbers `['a'] * 4` is equivalent to `['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a']`, hence `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`.

Comment: I disagree - each of the addends is itself a list.

Comment: Disagree with what? That's how `+` is defined for `list` operands.

Comment: If you are bothered by the mixed operands for `*`, consider the law `lst * n + lst * m == lst * (n+m)` instead, with `lst * 0 == []`.

Comment: make_a_list_from( 'a'  * 4), sure.

Comment: @Robin that doesn't make *any* sense, note `'a'*4 == 'aaaa'` which would be evaluated first...

Comment: But does the python behavior make sense without further elaboration? The unit being multiplied (i.e. repeatedly added) is a LIST containing 'a'. So repeatedly adding such lists should produce multiple lists, no?

Comment: No, the operand *is* the list, not the contents of the list.

Comment: If that's true then the result should be multiple lists, surely?

Comment: No, because adding two lists doesn't give you nested lists; why should multiplication?

Comment: @Robin no, surely it should not. The addition operator maps two `List[T]` objects to another `List[T]` objects (let''s simplify and think that lists in Python are not heterogenous). Try this for yourself: `['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a']`

Comment: Because adding two items of type X gives two items of type X. The outer braces in my suggestion are a container.

Comment: @Robin not generally, `2 + 2` doesn't give you two integers, it results in *another* integer.

Comment: What about concatenation then? ["2"] + ["2"] should give ["2"]["2"] or similar, maybe contained in a list themselves. I think there's some hidden set theory rules being applied that people are assuming are obvious, but which I think need making explicit. Or maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: @Robin no, no set theory. I mean, have you tried `["2"] + ["2"]` ? Is that also not intuitive to you? Because that would sort of simplify your question. Essentially, though, just take it as a "primitive" operation that `+` means concatenation of lists, in which case, multiplication is defined in terms of addition to make them consistent with the way those binary operators are usually defined

Comment: `["2"]["2"]` isn't even a thing; you are confusing the string representation of an object with the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

- just think this through.

```
['a'] * 4 == ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a']
```

- Adding two list should give list. This is defined behavior with python.
- If what you are saying is true then.

```
['a'] + ['a'] = [['a'],['a']].
```

- And what should be output of this?

```
['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] = [[['a'],['a']],['a']]  #??

['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] + ['a'] = [[[['a'],['a']],['a']],['a']] # ?????????
(['a']*2)*3 #  what should be output of this?
```

Comment: I'm not suggesting my alternative is practical. I just think the existing behaviour warrants some explanation.